# Komascript \minisec and prevent floating of floats

Tags: floats, sectioning, koma-script

We're using `\minisec{my fancy heading}` to generate several intermediate headings inside a chapter or section. But there are often also floats 'inside' these minisecs which sometimes float out of them.

For section (to paragraphs) we use the following code to prevent floating of objects outside the environment. My first idea was to re-use this code for `\minisec` but it doesn't work. I'm not sure if `\minisec` is a real section-like environment or just a nice looking intermediate heading.

Is there way to get this to work? A re-definition of `\minisec` would be the best solution for me.

Thx in advance!

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \expandafter\renewcommand\expandafter\minisec\expandafter{%
        \expandafter\@fb@secFB\minisec
    }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{My Section}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

\minisec{Minisec 1}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.

\begin{table}[htpb]
\caption{My table}
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{XXl}
  Lorem ipsum&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&Lorem ipsum\\
  Lorem ipsum&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&Lorem ipsum\\
  Lorem ipsum&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&Lorem ipsum\\
  Lorem ipsum&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&Lorem ipsum\\
  Lorem ipsum&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&Lorem ipsum\\
  Lorem ipsum&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&Lorem ipsum\\
  Lorem ipsum&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&Lorem ipsum\\
  Lorem ipsum&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&Lorem ipsum\\
  Lorem ipsum&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&Lorem ipsum\\
  Lorem ipsum&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&Lorem ipsum\\
  Lorem ipsum&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&Lorem ipsum\\
  Lorem ipsum&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&Lorem ipsum\\
  Lorem ipsum&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&Lorem ipsum
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\minisec{Minisec 2}
Text text Text text Text text 

\end{document}
```

Comment: This cannot work, because `\@fb@secFB` is undefined in your example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recommended solution to prevent floats from floating outside a document's region is to use [package `placeins`](https://ctan.org/pkg/placeins):

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{placeins}

\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\chapter{My Section}
\lipsum[1]

\minisec{Minisec 1}
\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{table}[htpb]
\caption{My table}
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{XXl}
  Lorem ipsum&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&Lorem ipsum\\
  Lorem ipsum&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&Lorem ipsum\\
  Lorem ipsum&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&Lorem ipsum\\
  Lorem ipsum&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&Lorem ipsum\\
  Lorem ipsum&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&Lorem ipsum\\
  Lorem ipsum&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&Lorem ipsum\\
  Lorem ipsum&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&Lorem ipsum\\
  Lorem ipsum&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&Lorem ipsum\\
  Lorem ipsum&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&Lorem ipsum\\
  Lorem ipsum&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&Lorem ipsum\\
  Lorem ipsum&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&Lorem ipsum\\
  Lorem ipsum&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&Lorem ipsum\\
  Lorem ipsum&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&Lorem ipsum
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\FloatBarrier
\minisec{Minisec 2}
Text text Text text Text text 

\end{document}
```

You can use [`xpatch`](https://ctan.org/pkg/placeins) to patch `\minisec` to always start with a `\FloatBarrier`:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretocmd{\minisec}{\FloatBarrier}{}{}

\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\chapter{My Section}
\lipsum[1]

\minisec{Minisec 1}
\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{table}[htpb]
\caption{My table}
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{XXl}
  Lorem ipsum&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&Lorem ipsum\\
  Lorem ipsum&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&Lorem ipsum\\
  Lorem ipsum&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&Lorem ipsum\\
  Lorem ipsum&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&Lorem ipsum\\
  Lorem ipsum&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&Lorem ipsum\\
  Lorem ipsum&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&Lorem ipsum\\
  Lorem ipsum&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&Lorem ipsum\\
  Lorem ipsum&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&Lorem ipsum\\
  Lorem ipsum&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&Lorem ipsum\\
  Lorem ipsum&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&Lorem ipsum\\
  Lorem ipsum&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&Lorem ipsum\\
  Lorem ipsum&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&Lorem ipsum\\
  Lorem ipsum&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&Lorem ipsum
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\minisec{Minisec 2}
Text text Text text Text text 

\end{document}
```

If you want to use the internal `placeins` command `\@fb@secFB`, you have to load `placeins` with option `section` before patching `\minisec` using `\AtBeginDocument`:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \xpretocmd{\minisec}{\@fb@secFB}{}{}%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\chapter{My Section}
\lipsum[1]

\minisec{Minisec 1}
\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{table}[htpb]
\caption{My table}
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{XXl}
  Lorem ipsum&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&Lorem ipsum\\
  Lorem ipsum&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&Lorem ipsum\\
  Lorem ipsum&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&Lorem ipsum\\
  Lorem ipsum&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&Lorem ipsum\\
  Lorem ipsum&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&Lorem ipsum\\
  Lorem ipsum&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&Lorem ipsum\\
  Lorem ipsum&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&Lorem ipsum\\
  Lorem ipsum&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&Lorem ipsum\\
  Lorem ipsum&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&Lorem ipsum\\
  Lorem ipsum&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&Lorem ipsum\\
  Lorem ipsum&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&Lorem ipsum\\
  Lorem ipsum&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&Lorem ipsum\\
  Lorem ipsum&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&Lorem ipsum
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\minisec{Minisec 2}
Text text Text text Text text 

\end{document}
```

Both examples result in:

[image: figure output before second minisec]